# How to skip other OR condition if first is matched in SELECT Query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having a trouble with `OR` condition inside the `SELECT`.

I want a simple result if one condition is matched and rest `OR` condition should not be use.

What i want is:

I have some users shared records and i would like to email them the newest items shared on my website.

> *For me: Newest Items will be least two days older*
>
> Like Today is 9th so i would like to pull all records of 7th. but if i
>   didn't get any record of 7th then i would like to pull all record of
>   6th (3 days older from today). if i didn't get any records on 6th then
>   i would like to pull 1 day older from today.

for all this i have used `OR` in my `SELECT` query like this:

```
SELECT `tg`.* FROM `tblgallery` AS `tg` WHERE (
(tg.added_date BETWEEN '2014-07-07 00:00:00' AND '2014-07-08 00:00:00') OR 
(tg.added_date BETWEEN '2014-07-06 00:00:00' AND '2014-07-07 00:00:00') OR 
(tg.added_date BETWEEN '2014-07-08 00:00:00' AND '2014-07-09 00:00:00') )
```

And i have records in my database for dates:

```
2014-07-06
2014-07-07
```

and when i run this query it gives me all record of both dates.

But I need to pull only record of `2014-07-07` not of both.(I have mentioned above.)

I know i can do this by using multiple `Select` and i think that will not be a good idea to request to database again and again.

My Question is : How to pull data from database if the first match is true? and skip all data of rest dates?

OR

Is there any other way to do this?

Please Help

Comment: +1 to the question cause I'm also interrested in knowing if a solution exists, other than doing queries one after each other until one of it sends results... Note that you could keep the query like it is and do the filtering in PHP.

Comment: @u_mulder : wouldn't that return no results as soon as there are records mathcing several conditions ?

Comment: @u_mulder- Checked but it gives me same results

Comment: `1 XOR 1 = 0`, `1 XOR 0 = 1`, `1 XOR 1 XOR 1 = 1` Generaly I think XOR wouldn't be a solution

Comment: @ShailParas I'm reading your comment below so ... isn't a better solution to have a `timestamp` for the last notification for each user; and then you would use this `WHERE date_added BETWEEN 'last-date-notified' AND CURDATE()`

Comment: @Bartdude - Please check the checked answer by fancyPants. may be it can help you.

Comment: Well I don't have the problem myself, but as I thought using XOR is not the solution at all and the solution is indeed not that simple :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually one would just work with `LIMIT`, which is not applicable here, since there might be many rows per day. What I do is quite similar to `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT
   tg.*,
   @gn := IF(DATE(tg.added_date) != @prev_date, @gn + 1, @gn) AS my_group_number,
   @prev_date := DATE(tg.added_date)
   FROM tblgallery tg
   , (SELECT @gn := 0, @prev_date := CURDATE()) var_init
   ORDER BY FIELD(DATE(tg.added_date), CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY, CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY) DESC
) sq
WHERE my_group_number = 1;
```

Here's how it works.

With this line

```
   , (SELECT @gn := 0, @prev_date := CURDATE()) var_init
```

the variables are initialized.

Then the `ORDER BY` is important! The [`FIELD()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_field) sorts the rows from `2 days ago` (gets value 3), to `3 days ago` (gets value 2), to `1 day ago` (gets value 1). Everything else gets value 0.

Then in the `SELECT` clause the order is also important.

With this line

```
   @gn := IF(DATE(tg.added_date) != @prev_date, @gn + 1, @gn) AS my_group_number,
```

the variable `@gn` is incremented when the date of the current row is different from the date of the previous row.

With this line

```
   @prev_date := DATE(tg.added_date)
```

the date of the current row is assigned to the variable `@prev_date`. In the line above it still has the value of the previous row.

Now those entries have a `1` in column `my_group_number` that have the most recent date in the order

```
2 days ago
3 days ago
yesterday
4 days ago
5 days ago
...
```

Comment: Thanks 
Right now i am not going to understand it, but i am going to say "ITS AWESOME". NOW i am searching my LUNCHBOX.. Its done hahaha.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Query:

```
SELECT GalleryID, PixName, A.added_date
FROM tblGallery A
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT added_date FROM tblGallery
  WHERE added_date <= DATE_SUB('2014-07-09 00:00:00', interval 2 day) 
  GROUP BY added_date
  ORDER BY added_date DESC
  LIMIT 1 ) B
ON A.added_date = B.added_date
```

See my <kbd>[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34d41/1)</kbd>

And even if the date is more than 2 days older it will still work.
See here the Demo below wherein the latest is 4 days older from July 9, 2014

See the <kbd>[**2nd Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8eb5e/1)</kbd>

And if you want the current date instead of literal date like here then you could use `CURDATE()` function instead. Like one below:

```
SELECT GalleryID, PixName, A.added_date
FROM tblGallery A
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT added_date FROM tblGallery
 WHERE added_date <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), interval 2 day) 
 GROUP BY added_date
 ORDER BY added_date DESC
 LIMIT 1 ) B
ON A.added_date = B.added_date
```

See <kbd>[**3rd Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8eb5e/2)</kbd>

Comment: You are setting interval of 2 days it means it will me only of 7th but what happen if there are no records on 7th. for me i will need 6th record if it gives nothing then 1 day later i mean should return 8th dates records..

Comment: It will still work even so. If you observe it says `adde_date` is `<=` to a minimum 2 days. Check my 2nd demo above @ShailParas.

Comment: Thanks friend, you 3rd demo is also worked, and also thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Well, actually it does not fullfil the OPs requirements. Requirement is, that data from 2 days ago is displayed. If there's none, data from 3 days ago has to be displayed. Till here your solution is right, but if there's no data from 3 days ago, data from **yesterday** has to be displayed. And here your solution fails.

Comment: Also performancewise your solution does unnecessary much. Instead of creating a temporary table (maybe including file sort) it probably would be much more efficient to join to `(select max(added_date) as a from added_date where added_date <= curdate() - interval 2 day)`

Comment: @fancyPants: Thanks your comment actually I missed out the last one, that is, if there no 2 or 3 days before the current date then just get the 1 day behind. I was looking more on the 2 or 3 days difference.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not being able to solve the multi OR issue but this is how could you get records being added last two days. Change the interval or the CURDATE() in order to fit your needs.

```
SELECT id, date_added
FROM gallery
WHERE date_added BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY AND CURDATE()
ORDER BY date_added
```

Check the [SQL Fiddel](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0769/1)

Answer (score 0):

It is not about how OR works in MySQL.
I think you are misunderstanding where part by looking at your discussion with @B.T. 
It will be executed for each record.
so if one of the record evaluates to false for the first condition then it will evaluate the second condition for that particular record and so on so if any condition evaluates to true by considering all the conditions then that will become part of your result set.

Try this query.

```
SELECT `tg`.* FROM `tblgallery` AS `tg` WHERE tg.added_date = (
select date (
select distinct(tg.added_date) date from tblgallery as tg
) as t1 order by case  
                    when date between '2014-07-07 00:00:00' AND '2014-07-08 00:00:00'
                        then 1
                    when date between '2014-07-06 00:00:00' AND '2014-07-07 00:00:00'
                        then 2
                    when date between '2014-07-08 00:00:00' AND '2014-07-09 00:00:00'
                        then 3
                    else 4
                end limit 1);
```

Here's what I am doing in this query.

- I am getting all the distinct dates.
- then I am ordering all the condition in order i.e if first condition is true then 1, if second is true then 2 and so on.
- I am limiting the result to 1 so after the order whichever the result is the first row will be selected and which is a date and will be used in the condition.

Note: I have note tested it yes, so you may need to do some changes to the query.